# Is there an easy way to animate a specific character in a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I want to fade a character in a string, so that `Whatever` turns into `Wha ever`.

```
$('p[2]').animate({ opacity: 0 });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EP3nR/1/)

I'd like to do it without wrapping each letter in HTML tags if possible.

Comment: You have to wrap each character in a tag to do that. `p[2]` in jQuery looks for a p tag with an attribute named 2.

Comment: Ok, I was hoping to avoid that.  There's no way to do without one?

Comment: @Squirrl it's not the id that's the issue, it's splitting the way the selector work as they are targeted at elements rather than text.

Comment: You can do it with a regular exp but without animate and opacity 0, I dont know if you want something like this

Comment: @laaposto Do u mean like replace a random character with a blank?

Comment: Any way to make that look like animate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap the character you want mask, to apply an effect on this element.

Try:

```
var hideLetter = function(element, position) {
    var str = $(element).text(),
        nstr = str.substr(0, position) + '<span>'  + str.substring(position, position + 1) + '</span>' + str.substring(position + 1);

    $(element).html(nstr);

    $(element).find('span').animate({
        opacity: 0
    });
};

hideLetter('p', 2);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uUYfL/2/)**

Comment: Nice. This is interesting.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps http://jsfiddle.net/EP3nR/5/

```
// Wrap each letter in a span tag
$('p').html(function(){
  return this.textContent.replace(/./g,'<span>$&</span>');
});

// Get 3rd char and hide it
var char = $('p').find('span').eq(2).animate({opacity:0}).text();

// The char that was hidden
$('h1').text(char);
```

You could also add the character **after** it gets hidden, using a callback:

```
$('p').find('span').eq(2).animate({opacity: 0}, function () {
  $('h1').text(this.textContent);
});
```

Comment: Nice answer too. Slick with the `$&`. Thanks.